# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in pos tagging(perceptron)

Tags: python

```
from textblob import Blobber
from textblob_aptagger import PerceptronTagger
blob1 = TextBlob("This is a blob.",pos_tagger=PerceptronTagger())
blob2 = TextBlob("This is another blob.")
print(blob1.tags)
```

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.844) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1531, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2016.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 938, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "D:/Tagger/Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(blob1.tags)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob\decorators.py", line 24, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 475, in pos_tags
    return [val for sublist in [s.pos_tags for s in self.sentences] for val in sublist]   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 475, in <listcomp>
    return [val for sublist in [s.pos_tags for s in self.sentences] for val in sublist]   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob\decorators.py", line 24, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(obj)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 478, in pos_tags
    for word, t in self.pos_tagger.tag(self)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob_aptagger\taggers.py", line 49, in tag
    for words in split_sents(corpus):   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob_aptagger\taggers.py", line 44, in split_sents
    for s in s_split(corpus):   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob\decorators.py", line 35, in decorated
    return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\textblob\tokenizers.py", line 57, in tokenize
    return nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 95, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1237, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1285, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in <listcomp>
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1316, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 312, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)   File "C:\Users\karthika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1289, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text): TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before ask.

Comment: Can you re-paste your traceback without putting it in quotes? It's unintelligible.